# CefSharp LoadHtml

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Could someone explain to me how the CefSharp `LoadHtml` function works?

```
LoadHtml(string html, string url)
```

What do the `html` and `url` parameters represent?

I am interested in loading a page from a raw HTML string into the CefSharp browser.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Update: CefSharp has a new `LoadHtml(string html)` method that loads the HTML as a base64-encoded data URI.  It is more reliable that the `LoadHtml(string html, string url)` method described below.

In `LoadHtml(string html, string url)`:

`html` is your HTML string, e.g. `"<html><body>Hello world</body></html>"`.  Actually, you can even put other content in the string, such as SVG markup, as long as Chromium can understand it.

`url` is needed because your HTML code may contain JavaScript that tries to perform AJAX calls, and the web browser needs to understand what security restrictions apply.  The scheme (e.g. "http:", "about:") and domain (e.g. "localhost", "google.com") affect behaviour such as clicking on links, AJAX requests, iframes, etc.

If you want to simply render static HTML, make the `url` something unique such as `http://rendering/` (so that the resource handler does not overlap with a real `url` on the web).  If you need to load the HTML and then interact with it or perform AJAX calls, choose a `url` that matches the domain you want to interact with - for example, if you want to make an alternative Google home page and perform AJAX search queries, you will want to use `https://www.google.com/` as your URL so you can communicate with it.

---

You can see the [source code for `LoadHtml` here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/aa7ef3c39522e2a89b4e253ebc25b732da845da6/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L1015-L1026).

What CefSharp does is:

1. Register a resource handler for the given `url`.
2. Call `Load(url)` to tell Chromium to load the given `url`.

Then, under the hood:

3. Chromium requests the `url`.
4. The resource handler intercepts the request, and returns your `html`.
5. Chromium renders your `html` instead of the real content of the URL.

Comment: Also the scheme has to be valid (eg can't use "oob://") otherwise the ResourceHandler just creates a Load Error (even though the URL is never going to be loaded).

Comment: This appears to be out of date with CefSharp 43.

Comment: Not sure if it is a later version issue, but I found if I supplied the url it wouldn't render my string. the sample on the cefsharp page shows no url https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/335c884b08caa74aba06a056105de30d3d0bc7c6/CefSharp.Example/JavascriptBinding/JavascriptCallbackBoundObject.cs

Comment: @DavidWilton that overload has a different implementation.  It loads the HTML as a data-uri: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/e3fcc90c2dd99a561d5c17ef046e47153af81eb6/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L432

Comment: LoadHTML(myHtml) works to render an html page. LoadHTML(myHTML, myURL) has yet to work with any value of myURL, e.g. "http://mydomain/". I get a mostly empty page with protocole reported as chrome-error:. Is there some config needed to make it work?

Comment: @R.Romero it has to be a valid URL with a scheme.  Try "http://rendering/"

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code

```
Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());

ChromiumWebBrowser browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(string.Empty) {
    Location = new Point(0, 0),
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill
};

//add to a System.Windows.Forms.Form or some other container.
this.Controls.Add(browser);
//the url parameter does not have to be an existing address.
browser.LoadHtml("<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>", "http://www.example.com/");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I download version 49.0.1 and I can't find the method `LoadHtml` any more, Is there any alternative method?

Comment: @Nguyen Minh Binh The LoadHtml method is present in the 49.0.1 source code -  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L271 . Maybe try to compile the source code?

Comment: I checked again, The method `LoadHtml` was move to `WebBrowserExtensions` package from v43. Before this version, this method available inside `CefSharp.Wpf` package. `https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/41/CefSharp.Wpf/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs`
Btw, I still don't know how to call this method rightnow from my ChromiumWebBrowser instance.

Comment: @Nguyen Minh Binh - Have a look at line 173 - https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/ViewModels/BrowserTabViewModel.cs#L163

Comment: Thank you for your time, but How to call this method from ChromiumWebBrowser instance? In my case, I decide to pull v41 and It works. I think this should be consider for whom want to use latest version.

Comment: It should be `CefSharp.WebBrowserExtensions.LoadHtml(browser, "<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>", "http://www.example.com/");`

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh the LoadHtml is an extension method located in the CefSharp namespace. You need to add an using directive like this: using CefSharp;

Comment: I just needed to import WebBrowserExtensions and LoadHtml will appear

Answer (score 4):

For a WPF project, try the following.

Create a namespace reference to CefSharp.Wpf in the xaml.

> xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"

Add the **ChromiumWebBrowser** element to your window.

```
<cef:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsBrowserInitializedChanged="browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged"></cef:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

Remember to assign a name to the element (in this case the element is called **browser**). We will use it to call the **LoadHtml** method later on.

Create an event handler for the **IsBrowserInitializedChanged** event. This is important, because this event will be fired once the **ChromiumWebBrowser** control is ready. Then can we load html.

Putting it all together...

### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CEF.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CEF"
    xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <cef:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="browser" IsBrowserInitializedChanged="browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged"></cef:ChromiumWebBrowser>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace CEF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void browser_IsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // the browser control is initialized, now load the html

            browser.LoadHtml("<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>", "http://www.example.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me
var s = "<html><head></head><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1></body></html>";
browser.LoadHtml(s);